# First time to Facebook Authenication with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, logic, theory

HI I am trying to understand FB Authenication theory to integrate in my web projects for the first time. As i want to know the data flow and theory rather than coding , so can anybody direct me where i can find some useful resources to get it understood.. 
Thanks

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can find all facebook SDK and Example files in the below link
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk